# Help with PHP looping system

Tags: php

Hey I have a set of results returned from the database, they are numbers which represent 1 - 18 which are the drivers_id, it could return any number of those dependant on how many drivers retired from a race. I am then matching them up to the users drivers and if they match then to -10 points from the users points.

If they do not match then to +5 points. If the query returns no set at all then i know that the users four drivers can be +5 points each, but if it returns 5 rows, then how can I loop through those and match them up? and if there is no match add +5 points to that drivers variable, but it has to be after all the result set has been compared as that driver might be a match to the next row in $row. Thanks a lot for any help provided!.

> p.s each driver_id in the result set is unique, so once a comparison
>   is true then that driver_id will not appear again.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT drivers_id FROM results_retired WHERE drivers_id IN ('$driver1', '$driver2', '$driver3', '$driver4') AND track_id = '$track'") or die ("Failed to update" . mysql_error());

$retireddrivers = mysql_fetch_array($results)

if(in_array($driver1, $retireddrivers)){
  $driveronepoints -= $driver_points_system["retired"];
}
else {
  $driveronepoints += $driver_points_system["completion"];
}
if(in_array($driver2, $retireddrivers)) {
  $drivertwopoints -= $driver_points_system["retired"];
}
else {
  $drivertwopoints += $driver_points_system["completion"];
}
if(in_array($driver3, $retireddrivers)) {
  $driverthreepoints -= $driver_points_system["retired"];
}
else {
  $driverthreepoints += $driver_points_system["completion"];
}
if(in_array($driver4, $retireddrivers)) {
  $driverfourpoints -= $driver_points_system["retired"];
}
else {
  $driverfourpoints += $driver_points_system["completion"];
}
```

I have made some changes now to the code, is the in_array function ok to use in this instance??

thanks

Comment: can you use the variable name like above inside the in array function to compare against the arrays contents.

Comment: can you show us where $driver1, $driver2, etc... comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the concept of rows vs columns.

`mysql_fetch_*` will return you one row -- that is, *one* of the retired drivers' IDs -- with each call.  You'll need to collect them into an array before you can use `in_array`.

```
while ($retired_driver = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    $retireddrivers[] = $retired_driver['driver_id'];
}
```

Also, if you can manage it, i'd consider putting drivers 1-4 into an array as well.  Then you can do like

```
// Ideally, $driver[1-4]* won't exist at all -- you'd pull the info from the DB,
// or from the form, and stuff it directly into the array.
// This code right here is just to make existing code work
$drivers = array(
    array('id' => $driver1, 'points' => &$driver1points),
    array('id' => $driver2, 'points' => &$driver2points),
    array('id' => $driver3, 'points' => &$driver3points),
    array('id' => $driver4, 'points' => &$driver4points),
);

foreach ($drivers as $driver)
{
    if (in_array($driver['id'], $retireddrivers))
    {
        $driver['points'] -= $driver_points_system['retired'];
    }
    else
    {
        $driver['points'] += $driver_points_system['completion'];
    }
}
```

considerably reducing duplication of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have just been having problems with how to effictively loop though with the optimized code. This has gave me a useful insight! thanks again. So now the points for each $driver and each drivers ID is inside one array?

Comment: Yeah..the driver's ID and points are bundled together in one array per driver.  `$drivers[0]['id']` would be the first driver's ID, and `$drivers[0]['points']` would be their points.  If ever you want to clean stuff up, the arrays would be good candidates for turning into a Driver class, but for now arrays work well enough.